# Изменить строку соединения в App.config

Tags: c#

Так получаю строку соединения введенную юзером:

```
DataConnectionDialog dcd = new DataConnectionDialog();
DataConnectionConfiguration dcs = new DataConnectionConfiguration(null);
dcs.LoadConfiguration(dcd);

if (DataConnectionDialog.Show(dcd) == DialogResult.OK)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(dcd.ConnectionString))
    {
        //..
    }
}

dcs.SaveConfiguration(dcd);
```

Как сделать, чтобы вся программа работала именно с этой строкой?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Сохраните строку подключения к БД в конфигурационном файле app.config

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyConnectionString" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="data source=sqlserver;Initial Catalog=BD;User Id=user;Password=password" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Из app.config вы ее легко прочитаете с помощью класса `ConfigurationManager`в любом участке кода

```
string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

Если вы хотите ее заменить в runtime, то сделайте так

```
    var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
    var connectionStringsSection = (ConnectionStringsSection)config.GetSection("connectionStrings");         
    connectionStringsSection.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString = "Data Source=serverChange;Initial Catalog=BDD;user=user1;password=password";
    config.Save();
    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");
```

Если вы попытаетесь прочитать строку подключения снова, то получите измененную строку подключения

Comment: Спасибо за отзыв,использовал второе случай,все нормально соединяет,но у меня форме есть **DataGridView** которое заполняется из базы вот так  ` this.animalBaseInfoTableAdapter.Fill(this.bandivanKatDataSet.AnimalBaseInfo);`  но когда пытаюсь открыть форму вылетает исключения с сообщением

Comment: сообщение исключения  **Дополнительные сведения: При установлении соединения с SQL Server произошла ошибка, связанная с сетью или с определенным экземпляром. Сервер не найден или недоступен. Убедитесь, что имя экземпляра указано правильно и что на SQL Server разрешены удаленные соединения. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Не удалось открыть подключение к SQL Server)**

Answer (score 0):

Надо вынести создание SqlConnection в отдельный метод.
А соединение хранить в поле формы.
Примерно так

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace App {
    public class Form {
        string GetConnection() {
            DataConnectionDialog dcd = new DataConnectionDialog();
            // ...
            return new SqlConnection(dcd.ConnectionString);
        }

        SqlConnection connection;

        public Form() {
            // добавляем кнопку; при ее нажатии создается соединение.
            new Button() { Parent = this }
               .Click += (s, e) => 
                  // сохраняем соединение
                  connection = GetConnection();
        }
    }
}
```